# Remove linked account/token programmatically

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a project and enabled account linking (using authorisation code) against my oauth2 provider.

Linking an account works fine and next times Google Assistant calls my fulfilment webhook, **accessToken** gets passed along other user data.

However, if this token gets invalidated in my system, Google does not know about it. When this situation arises (i.e. my webhook receives a token which is now invalid) I would like to notify Google (so that it can get rid of this invalid link) and/or re-send a prompt to link your account.

I tried calling the sign-in helper (as below) but that did not work.

```
app.askForSignIn();
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?